# rewrite rules social share links

Tags: url-rewriting, facebook, rewrite-rules, twitter

Within the Ultimatum's theme childtheme.php I've added rewrite rules to the rewrite rules and it works perfectly fine. However, it does not work if the URL is shared in Facebook or Twitter.

The Facebook debugger returns "Could Not Follow Redirect Path" for any of the pages using the rewrite rule.

URL to try: http://www.teamrealty.ca/listing-details/839215/res/5801-Longhearth-Wa/
debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.teamrealty.ca%2Flisting-details%2F839215%2Fres%2F5801-Longhearth-Wa%2F

#### rewrite rules function

```
function AddRewriteRules ($ar_rules)
{
    $ar_new_rules = array('listing-details/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=listing-details&mls=$matches[1]&ret=$matches[2]');
    $ar_rules = $ar_new_rules + $ar_rules;
    return $ar_rules;
}
// hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'AddRewriteRules');
```

Comment: This rewrite rule doesn't redirect (only, well, rewrites), I see no redirect on the link at all in [REDbot](https://redbot.org/?uri=http://www.teamrealty.ca/listing-details/839215/res/5801-Longhearth-Wa/). Not sure what's Facebook problem, since it requires login. Can you reproduce in some public tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rel canonical link points to `http://www.teamrealty.ca/listing-details/`, which returns a 500 internal server error response code. You can try to remove the canonical action before `wp_head()` is called on those pages:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo. That lead me in the right direction and I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430623/wordpress-auto-generated-canonical-links-how-to-add-a-custom-url-parameter and I'm using something similar. The remove_action is not working though. I now get two canonical link tags.

Comment: probably an SEO plugin adding it.